# IdentityServer4 Exception Handling

Tags: asp.net-core, exception, identityserver4

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 MVC Application that makes use of OIDC authentication provided by IdentityServer4.

In the Identity Project (also ASP.Net Core 3.1) the login process sometimes fails on the following routes with the following errors:

`/connect/token` fails with `Invalid authorization code`

`/connect/authorize` fails with `Request validation failed` or `client_id is missing or too long`

These result in the general Exception page being returned to the user.  I suspect that these stem from users that are using bad browser shortcuts (but I'm not 100% sure about this, so any advice on the source of these would be appreciated).  But my actual question is... What exception handling can I put in place to return a more meaningful message to the user, something like an error response that says

> please check the browser shortcut you used to access this logon page!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here, you can use the

app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

or create your own middleware to capture the exceptions thrown by the authentication middleware in ASP.NET Core to present the user with a meaningful errors.

Some errors/events can also be caught and handled using the [OpenID Connect middleware event model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents?view=aspnetcore-5.0)